# Modifying menu color of a gtk 3.0 theme

Tags: gtk, theme

I'm trying to integrate a GTK3.0 theme with xfwm4 theme, 
[image]

Now I need to change the menu background color, so I get the color value with `gcolor` and tried to `grep` for that value, nothing found under the `gtk-3.0` folder.

What's the right way of doing it?

**EDIT**

[Faience GTK3.0 theme](http://tiheum.deviantart.com/art/GTK3-Gnome-Shell-Faience-255097456)

[ZukiMac xfwm4 theme](http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php?content=147848)

Comment: @don_crissti edited question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way is to read the `gtk-*.css` files and figure it out... [Gtk+3 theming](http://funsurf-blog.blogspot.com/2012/06/when-you-make-gtk3-theme.html) allows you to play with colors in various ways:

> You can either use the **hex, rgb or rgba values to represent colors**, or
>   you can use the symbolic colors which are defined in the gtk.css file
>   prefixed by a @ symbol. You can also manipulate the colors **using
>   alpha, shade, mix etc**. for adding transparency, **darkening** the color
>   and **mixing two colors** respectively.

So, in your particular case - Faience GTK, the files in question are `gtk-main.css` and `gtk-widgets.css` (the latter usually references colors defined in the former).
In `gtk-widgets.css` line 994 (the *menubar* section) you have:

```
background-color: @toolbar_gradient_start;
```

means the menu background color is `toolbar_gradient_start` defined in `gtk-main.css` line 44:

```
@define-color toolbar_gradient_start shade (@theme_bg_color, 0.85);
```

So `toolbar_gradient_start` is a shade of `theme_bg_color`, defined on line 2 as `#eeeeee`. If you open `gcolor2` and enter `#eeeeee` you'll get the rgb code (238,238,238). As per the above color definition, 0.85 shade means rgb (203,203,203) which in hex is `#CBCBCB` which is exactly what `gcolor2` reports if I use the color picker on the menubar in your screenshot.

So basically, the color you are after is a shade of the main gtk theme background color defined in `gtk-main.css`. Altering the color definition would change the color, e.g. (I commented out the original code):

```
@define-color toolbar_gradient_start #f05959;
@define-color toolbar_gradient_end #e9a2a2;
/* @define-color toolbar_gradient_start shade (@theme_bg_color, 0.85);
@define-color toolbar_gradient_end shade (@theme_bg_color, 0.75); */
```

would make the menubar look like this:

[image]

Comment: Good, now I have everything look the same ;-P